# Compile release mode for android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have an app that runs great in debug mode, with the android option of 'Use Shared Runtime' checked. Once I set up in Release mode (where that option NEEDS to be unchecked), I am getting a runtime error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies

I cannot find this reference anywhere in my project, and have no clue as to how to fix it.

This is a VS2017 xamarin project in C# with latest SDKs loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to replicate your problem, this is a complete stab in the dark so I apologise in advance if it doesn’t solve your particular problem. I have recently been having a similar issue where VS wouldn’t recognise that the System package was installed. It might be worth trying to restore the NuGet packages solution and rebuilding it. That fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: ok - so I updated all the nuGet packages, restarted VS, and no change.

Comment: I'm sorry this is a late response. I didn't see a notification for your comments. If you're still having the problem, I was actually talking about the restore NuGet packages menu option. First, here's some information about [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) that you might want to know if you have any specific package versions you need to use. If you want to go ahead with the restore, right click on your solution in the solution explorer and click 'Restore NuGet Packages'.